# how to arrange mysql query results starting from a particular row

Tags: mysql

assuming you have a records with IDs 1,2,3,4,5. How would you construct your query so that the results returned will be arranged starting with ID number 3. eg 3,4,5,1,2

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CASE` in `ORDER` will do it:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table`
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN id >= 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
    id ASC
```

Comment: @user2922439 If your problem is solved then accept answer so, In future helpful to other user